# Recursively going through array and counting pixels

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I'm tasked with creating a method that is given a position (int x, int y) and it expands from that position and finds all pixels within the array that have the same color as the original position. I am supposed to find this position recursively, but I'm continuously getting the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Code:

```
public int sizeOfConnectedComponent(Position p) {
    if ((rows > pixels.length || cols > pixels[0].length) || (rows < 0 || cols < 0)) {
        return 0;
    } else if (!pixels[rows][cols] || visited[rows][cols]) {

        return 0;
    } else {

        visited[rows][cols] = true;

        sizeOfConnectedComponent((new Position(rows - 1, cols)));
        sizeOfConnectedComponent((new Position(rows + 1, cols)));
        sizeOfConnectedComponent((new Position(rows, cols - 1)));
        sizeOfConnectedComponent((new Position(rows, cols + 1)));
        {
            if (visited[rows][cols] == true){
                total++;
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

The error occurs on the line `if (!pixels[rows][cols] || visited[rows][cols])`. Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: What is pixels[rows][cols]? is it a variable in 2D matrix or a boolean value?

Comment: Well, it seems like a value you are using as an index is exceeding the array size.

Comment: How come, you don't use the variable p? And since you're not using it, I don't see a way, how 'rows' and 'cols' can change their value at any time...

Comment: I apologize for my lack of details. Each pixel is a boolean. True is a black pixel, and false is a white pixel.

Comment: Why did you delete the code from your post? The question doesn’t have enough details now.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have the line:

```
if ((rows > pixels.length || cols > pixels[0].length) || (rows < 0 || cols < 0))
```

With the code as it is, it's possible for `rows` and `cols` to be the same length as the array itself, which could cause the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

For example:

```
int rows = 3;
int[] pixels = new int[3];

if (rows > pixels.length) { // This evaluates to false and won't return.
    return 0;               // 'rows > pixels.length' is the same as '3 > 3' which equals false.
}                  

pixels[rows]; // Then, when you try to use 'rows' as the index, you get an error because
              // the maximum array index is always array.length-1
```

So instead of:

```
(rows > pixels.length || cols > pixels[0].length)
```

it should be:

```
(rows >= pixels.length || cols >= pixels[0].length)
```

Also, you don't check if the `rows` and `cols` are out of bounds for your `visited` array.